# Initializing an array on arbitrary starting index in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, interop, ms-office, initialization

Is it possible in c# to initialize an array in, for example, subindex 1?

I'm working with Office interop, and every property is an object array that starts in 1 (I assume it was originally programed in VB.NET), and you cannot modify it, you have to set the entire array for it to accept the changes.

As a workaround I am cloning the original array, modifying that one, and setting it as a whole when I'm done.

But, I was wondering if it was possible to create a new non-zero based array

Comment: vb.net arrays start at 0, too.

Comment: But you can create them if you want them not to (new Array(3 to 5) or something like that)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Array.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

See [Array Types in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301755.aspx)

Comment: I really wanted to know if it was syntactically possible, but this is a great solution

Comment: Please include code in your answers rather than linking to documents that may not exist tomorrow.

Answer (score 19):

It is possible to do as you request see the code below.

```
// Construct an array containing ints that has a length of 10 and a lower bound of 1
Array lowerBoundArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new int[1] { 10 }, new int[1] { 1 });

// insert 1 into position 1
lowerBoundArray.SetValue(1, 1);

//insert 2 into position 2
lowerBoundArray.SetValue(2, 2);

// IndexOutOfRangeException the lower bound of the array 
// is 1 and we are attempting to write into 0
lowerBoundArray.SetValue(1, 0);
```

Comment: +1: One block of useful code is worth a thousand links of unreadable prose *about* code.

Comment: any way to type this as int[] instead of Array?

Answer (score 1):

Not simply.  But you can certainly write your own class.  It would have an array as a private variable, and the user would think his array starts at 1, but really it starts at zero and you're subtracting 1 from all of his array accesses.

Comment: Yeah, you can always do anything yourself... the question is if it can be done with c# syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own array class

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if it's possible to modify the starting index of arrays.

I would create my own array using generics and handle it inside.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep of const int named 'offset' with a value of one, and always add that to your subscripts in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create non-zero based arrays in C#, but you could easily write a wrapper class of your own around the built in data structures.This wrapper class would hold a private instance of the array type you required; overloading the [] indexing operator is not allowed, but you can add an indexer to a class to make it behave like an indexable array, see [here](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/1547581). The index function you write could then add (or subtract) 1, to all index's passed in.

You could then use your object as follows, and it would behave correctly:

```
myArrayObject[1]; //would return the zeroth element.
```

Answer (score -1):

In VB6 you could change the array to start with 0 or 1, so I think VBScript can do the same. For C#, it's not possible but you can simply add NULL value in the first [0] and start real value at [1]. Of course, this is a little dangerous...

Comment: The properties require the array to start in 1, so this wouldn't work