# How can I create an ArrayList with a starting index of 1 (instead of 0)

Tags: c#, java, arraylist

How can I start the index in an `ArrayList` at 1 instead of 0? Is there a way to do that directly in code?

(Note that I am asking for `ArrayList`, for plain arrays please see [Initializing an array on arbitrary starting index in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82943/initializing-an-array-on-arbitrary-starting-index-in-c-sharp))

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: @Eric I will say why,in the first year in our university the students take Pascal and the indexing here starts from 1 so they asked if they can do the same thing with c# (just a question).

Comment: How about not using `ArrayList` at all?  In .NET, at least, it's been superseded by the generic collections since 5 years ago.

Comment: I didn't say I want to do that,it was just a question!

Comment: Can they do the same thing with c#? Yes. Should they? No.

Comment: When you learn spanish, you don't ask "Is there any way speak english and have them understand me?".  The same is true of comptuer languages.  When you "speak" a computer language, you must use it's vocabulary.  C# has arrays that begin with 0.  If you want to begin with 1, write Pascal.

Comment: I currently have a business requirement that consists in porting the calculation code written by an engineer in VBA Excel and integrate it in our automation service architecture in C#. The engineer knows a lot about calculations, and rather less about programming. He has done his best and has used arrays a intensive way for his linear equations algorithm.
Because it must be done, I dont have time to waste to rewrite all the array logic, and I have now a very good reason having special arrays that starts with 1 in C#. This can be done cleanly and be well documented. So THANKS for this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The obvious way to do it would be to wrap an ArrayList in your own implementation, and subtract 1 from the indexer in all operations that uses the index.

You can in fact also declare an array in .NET, that has an [arbitrary lower bound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301755.aspx) (Scroll down to the section "Creating Arrays with a Non-zero Lower Bound").

With that said, please don't do it in production code. It matters to be consistent.

Answer (score 10):

One legitimate reason to do this is in writing unit tests.  Certain 3rd party SDKs (for example Excel COM interop) expect you to work with arrays that have one-based indices.  If you're working with such an SDK, you can and should stub out this functionality in your C# test framework.

The following should work:

```
object[,] comInteropArray = Array.CreateInstance(
    typeof(object),
    new int[] { 3, 5 },
    new int[] { 1, 1 }) as object[,];

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(
     1 == comInteropArray.GetLowerBound(0),
    "Does it look like a COM interop array?");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(
     1 == comInteropArray.GetLowerBound(1),
    "Does it still look like a COM interop array?");
```

I don't know if it's possible to cast this as a standard C# style array.  Probably not. I also don't know of clean way to hard-code the initial values of such an array, other than looping to copy them from a standard C# array with hard-coded initial values.  Neither of these shortcomings should be a big deal in test code.

Comment: I noticed that my comment applies to arrays, not ArrayLists.  Oops.  I hope people working with Excel and VTSO will still find it useful, even though it strays from the original question.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could make your own:

```
public class MyArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    public T get(int index) {
        super.get(index - 1);
    }

    public void set(int index, T value) {
        super.set(index - 1, value);
    }
}
```

But it begs the question: why on earth would you bother?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it still does, but at one point, Visual Basic would let you start your array indexes at 1 with [`Option Base 1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(VS.60).aspx).

In C#, none of the System.Collections collections support this, but you could always write a wrapper class that does the index translation for you.

Really, though, this should be avoided.  VB's `Option Base` created more problems than it solved, I imagine because it broke assumptions and made things more confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something I am using right now to quickly port a VBA application to C#:

It's an Array class that starts with 1 and accepts multiple dimensions.

Although there is some additional work to do (IEnumerator, etc...), it's a start, and is enough to me as I only use indexers.

```
public class OneBasedArray<T>
{
    Array innerArray;

    public OneBasedArray(params int[] lengths)
    {
        innerArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), lengths, Enumerable.Repeat<int>(1, lengths.Length).ToArray());
    }

    public T this[params int[] i]
    {
        get
        {
            return (T)innerArray.GetValue(i);
        }
        set
        {
            innerArray.SetValue(value, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic! I am converting some old Spectrum Basic games and this is invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Stuff getValueAtOneBasedIndex(ArrayList<Stuff> list, index) {
     return list.get(index -1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers suggest, there are ways to simulate this, but no direct way to do this in C# or other commonly used .NET languages.  Quoting [Eric Gunnerson](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/03/16/90724.aspx):

> The CLR does support this kind of
>   construct (I had a hard time not using
>   the term "travesty" here...), but
>   there aren't, to my knowledge, any
>   languages that have built-in syntax to
>   do that.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me preface this answer by explaining my use case: Excel Interop. It's much easier to read and write data using arrays, but Excel Range.Value2 magically returns a 1 based object array.

So, if you are writing to Excel and that's the reason you are asking this question in the first place... then perhaps stop fighting c# and let Excel instantiate the array for you. So instead of:

```
object[,] newArray = new object[indexR, indexC];
```

You can use:

```
object[,] newArray = (object[,])RangeToWriteTo.Value2;
```

In my case, I created a wrapper class to allow me to use an array for the properties like so:

```
public abstract class ExcelRowBase
    {
        public object[,] data;

        public ExcelRowBase(int index)
        {
            data = new object[2, index + 1];
        }
    }

 public class InstanceRowModel : ExcelRowBase 
    {
        public InstanceRowModel() : base(8) 
        { 
        //constructor unique to Wire Table 
        }

        public object Configuration
        {
            get
            {
                return data[1, 1];
            }
            set
            {
                data[1, 1] = value;
            }
        }
...
```

So in all cases, I'm reading from the same index. So to make the transition from a model I'm passing into a Create method, I just need to copy over the properties into the model that uses the array created from Excel.

```
            insertingModel.data = (object[,])writeRange.Value2;

            //manually copying values from one array to the other
            insertingModel.Configuration = model.Configuration;
            ...

            writeRange.Value2 = insertingModel.data;
```

This works for me for now because I only have to do this in the create function. In update / get / delete, you're getting the Excel based array anyway. Perhaps a future improvement would be to create an Excel range factory that avoids the 0 based default construction all together, but this solution just gave me greens on my tests, so I'm moving on!