# Getting and re-assigning values from a List

Tags: c#

I am looping through a list and I will like to set the index number to be 1 when there is a specific value found in the list. I would like to get the sequenceNumber or /index counting from 1. If **EN** is in the list, I would like set a sequence number of 1 and the rest of the values should start from two. The list of countries is read from a file and could be more.
Here is my code

```
public static List<TResult> GetValues<TResult>(Func<string, string, int, TResult> createType)
        where TResult : class
{

    var dynamicCountryList = new List<string>(new [] {"DE", "EN", "PT", "FR"}) 
    // this list is dynamic and can be populated by the program.
    
    var staticCountryList = new List<string>(); // created this to get the sequence values
    var numberOfCountries= countryList.Count;
    foreach (var country in dynamicCountryList)
    {
        if (!staticCountryList.Contains(country)
        {
           staticCountryList.Add(country)
        }
        var sequenceNumber = numberOfCountries == 1  && country == "EN" 
                                ? staticCountryList.IndexOf("EN") + 1 
                                : numberOfCountries == 1 && country != "EN" 
                                ? 2
                                : numberOfCountries > 1 && country!= "EN" && staticCountryList.IndexOf(country) < 1
                                ? sequenceNumberList.IndexOf(country) + 3
                                : numberOfCountries> 1 && country!= "EN" && staticCountryList.IndexOf(lang) == 1
                                ? staticCountryList.IndexOf(country) + 1
                                : staticCountryList.IndexOf(country);

       result.Add(createType(string.Empty, string.Empty, sequenceNumber));
    }
```

Even if **EN** is the 20th item on the List, i will like to assign a value of 1 and the rest can be ordered in the manner in which they were added to the list (like 1,2,3,4...etc). Any help with this?

**Edit***

Basically dynamicCountryList is read by the program from a file but it is stated here for simplicity.I am reading from several files and per file we could have the following values from a single file

1. DE
2. EN
3. PT
4. FR
5. FI

I will like to assign a value of 1 to the `sequenceNumber`  if EN is found in the list. The next values would be 2 for DE, 3 for PT, 4 for FR, 5 for FI and so on (depending if the list is longer). EN must have a value of 1 if found in the list. If there is no EN in the list, then we should start from a value of 2. Meaning no other country is allowed to have a value of 1.

Comment: What is `countryList` and how does it differ from `dynamicCountryList` or `staticCountryList`? Having that many nested items in a ternary is basically begging for bugs. Seems like it should be a simple matter of a couple of `if`s, but it's not clear where `lang` is coming from.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I just edited the quesion and hope it is clear now.

Comment: I could not think of a better way to get the sequence or index of each value because I need to start counting from 1 and the sequenceNumber should be 1 when EN is in the list and if not in the list, then in my exampple sequenceNumber should be 2 when the loop is in DE, 3 when in PT, 4 when in FR and 5 when in FI

Comment: The problem is that `List<T>` already has a 0-based index with each entry. So the first entry has index 0. If you use [`Insert(int, T)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=net-5.0) to insert an element at a specific index, all other elements will have their indexes updated automatically. But your code has so many lists and variables referenced that I can't make heads or tails out of it, If you must, you could use one of the answers to [c# how do i make my list 1 based rather than 0 based](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12527639/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about first checking for "EN" in the list, and then looping through the rest of it?

```
public static List<TResult> GetValues<TResult>(Func<string, string, int, TResult> createType)
        where TResult : class
{

    var dynamicCountryList = new List<string>(new[] { "DE", "EN", "PT", "FR" })
    // this list is dynamic and can be populated by the program.
          
    if (dynamicCountryList.Contains("EN"))
    {
        result.Add(createType(string.Empty, string.Empty, 1));
    }

    int sequenceNumber = 2;
    foreach (var country in dynamicCountryList)
    {
        // "EN" condition already handled, just go on to the next one.
        if (country == "EN")
        {
            continue;
        }

        result.Add(createType(string.Empty, string.Empty, sequenceNumber));
        sequenceNumber++;
    }
}
```