# C# Is there a way of declaring non zero lower bound array typeof(dynamic)

Tags: c#, vb6-migration

I need it to interface vb6 library which expects that form of output array to do some calculations on data. Is there any form of workaround since I cannot use statement `typeof(dynamic)` in array declaration only `typeof(object)`...

What I have tried so far:

```
System.Array Outputs = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Object), 1);
System.Array Outputs = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), 1);
System.Array Outputs = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(dynamic), 1); // Compilation error
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to [so], can you please provide some code [mcve] and details on your research so far.

Comment: Hello.I edited the question and now it includes the code

Comment: What do you mean by "non zero lower bond array" ?

Comment: Normally in c# c++ the first element of array has index 0.In Early VB (that changed in vb.net) the first element of array is indexed as 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create an ArrayList with a starting index of 1 (instead of 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799088/how-can-i-create-an-arraylist-with-a-starting-index-of-1-instead-of-0)

Comment: Unfortunately the second part of the question regarding dynamic object is still is actual

Comment: What if you just use a regular, 0 based array? from it's name it should hold the output of the method, so you can simply ignore what's on the first cell

Comment: Unfortunately the array is used inside a function which directly comes from vb6 library which requires nonzero lower bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dynamic` really only exists at compile-time. If you create a `List<dynamic>` for example, that's really creating a `List<object>`. As such, it doesn't make sense to use `typeof(dynamic)` which is why the third line fails to compile. If you're passing the array to other code, it's up to that other code how it uses the array - there's nothing that would exist at execution time to "know" that it's meant to be dynamically typed.

But in order to create an array, you've got to provide a *length*. The overload of `Array.CreateInstance` you're using always uses a lower bound of zero. You want the overload accepting two *arrays* of integers - one for lengths and one for lower bounds. For example:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Array outputs = Array.CreateInstance(
            typeof(object), // Element type
            new[] { 5 },    // Lengths                                             
            new[] { 1 });   // Lower bounds

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            outputs.SetValue($"Value {i}", i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Set indexes 1-5 successfully");
        // This will throw an exception
        outputs.SetValue("Bang", 0);        
    }
}
```