# How to do typeof object[*] in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm fairly new to C# but have searched the web for an hour and no joy...

I need to ascertain whether an object is a non-zero index array, i.e. object[*]

I've tried:

```
if(v != null && v.GetType() == typeof(object[*]))
```

and
    if(v is object[*])

as well as overloaded methods Method(object v) and Method(object[*] v)

All result in compilation errors.

As I can't cast object[*] to object[] and then test GetLowerBound(0) how the hell can I test this type?

(Please don't tell me this bad code/design, it's coming from Excel so I obviously cannot change that).

Comment: Where did you get the `[*]` syntax from? I've never seen that.

Comment: It's to denote non-zero based index arrays, i.e. arrays that don't start at [0].  Used a lot in Excel code (where they start at 1).

Comment: what do you mean "non zero index array"?

Comment: For interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82943/initializing-an-array-on-arbitrary-starting-index-in-c-sharp

Comment: @AndreiG an array whose lower bound is something other than zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Type.IsArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isarray.aspx), [Type.GetArrayRank](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getarrayrank.aspx) and [Type.GetElementType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx) if necessary.

If you need to call `GetLowerBound` you can safely cast the object to `System.Array`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want:

```
Array array = v as Array;
if(array != null && array.GetLowerBound(0) != 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Test:

```
var array = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new[] { 3 }, new[] { 1 });
Console.WriteLine(array.GetType());
Console.WriteLine(array.GetLowerBound(0));
```

Output:

```
System.Object[*]
1
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer with code, @Andre Loker got there a first so accepting his answer, but thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

If the object is really typed as `object[]` and not as `string[]` or some other array then this will do

```
typeof(object[])
```

A placeholder for the array size is not required, since this is the normal way of declaring arrays

```
object[] myObjectArray;
```

---

EDIT:

In your case, you could simplify the statement to

```
if(v is object[])
```

since

```
((object[])null) is object[]
```

yields `false`

Comment: It isn't, as you cannot cast object[*] to object[]. [*] is not a placeholder

Comment: The star `*` is the placeholder. What I mean is, write `object[]`, not `object[*]`.

Comment: No StackOverflow took the two asterisks and formatted middle bit to italic.  Asterisk is not a placeholder in this context, objeft[ASTERISK] is a non-zero based-index array, i.e. not starting at zero.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Arrays declared in C# have always a zero-based index. Non-zero-based indexes apply only to arrays returned by COM-APIs (e.g. by Excel).

Comment: By the way. You can escape code-parts with accent-grave, a kind of backslash apostrophy. The key below the ESC key on my US-ASCII keyboard. --> `

Comment: Thanks Oliver, same place on GB keyboard =)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Object [] v = new Object[2];

 if (!ReferenceEquals(v, null))
          {
              if ((v.GetType() is System.Object)
                  && (v.GetType().IsArray))
              {

              }
          }
```

but just 'v' is initialize not your objects inside !!!