# pass two dimensional arrays parameter to a func in COM dll, from VB6 vs from C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, parameters, com, vb6

I have a 3rd party numeric COM dll that does linear regression. 
Here's how legacy VB6 code calls it (and works well)

```
Dim Y() As Variant, X() As Variant
ReDim Y(1 To rs.RecordCount), X(1 To rs.RecordCount, 1 To 2)
' fill Y and X with some data
Coeff = MathLib.LinearRegression(Y, X)
```

But I got some problems calling it from C#.

In C#, it works when X() is one dimensional:

```
int[] x0 = new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int[] y0 = new int[] { 10, 11, 12, 13 };
object z0 = MathLib.LinearRegression(y0, x0);
```

This C# code, where x0 is 2 dimensional, I got exception "dimension error"

```
int[,] x0 = new int[,] {{2,4},{6,8},{1,3},{5,7},};
int[] y0 = new int[] { 10, 11, 12, 13 };
object z0 = MathLib.LinearRegression(y0, x0);
```

This C# code, where x0 is array of array, I got exception "Specified array was not of the expected type"

```
int[][] x0 = new int[][] {
    new int[]{2,4},
    new int[]{6,8},
    new int[]{1,3},
    new int[]{5,7},
};
int[] y0 = new int[] { 10, 11, 12, 13 };
object z0 = MathLib.LinearRegression(y0, x0);
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Depending on how the DLL is written, you might be forced to create an [array with particular lower/upper bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/q/82943/11683). Does the VB6 code work if you change `1 To 2` to `0 To 1`?

Comment: That's one, for another an array of variants is an object[] or object[,] in C#.

Comment: @GSerg, yes, forgot to mention, VB6 code works when I changed 1-based index to 0-based index. thx.

Comment: @HansPassant, object[,] seems to work, the returned regression coefficients are all null, but at least the exception is gone. I will figure out the rest. Thank you!