# Start Index Of Multidimensional Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have one method which returns `Multidimensional Array`. When I expand and see the data start from index `[1,1]` how this is done with C# ?

**There is no [0,0], [0,1] ...**

**It start from**

```
[1,1]
[1,2]
[1,3]
```

...

When I initialize for example `object[,] = new object[5,5];`
The data start from index `[0,0].`

Here is the whole code

```
Worksheet cSheet = (Worksheet)workBookE.Worksheets[i];
Range range = cSheet.UsedRange;
string address = range.get_Address();
string[] cells = address.Split(new char[] { ':' });
string beginCell = cells[0].Replace("$", "");
string endCell = cells[1].Replace("$", "");
object[,] objectArray = (object[,])cSheet.get_Range(beginCell + ":" + endCell).Value2; // here the index starts from 1,1
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to reproduce it? Are you expanding it in Visual Studio debug view? What if not expand it but try to get element[0,0]?

Comment: In this case comes from excel.

Comment: No, that's not how it's done. C# arrays are zero indexed.

Comment: "Then I expand and see the data start from index [1,1]" Do you expand it in a debugger?

Comment: Its same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82943/initializing-an-array-on-arbitrary-starting-index-in-c-sharp

Comment: @JonasElfström Not always - you can create a 1-based multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks, I didn't know that. How strange of them to allow that for multi- but not for one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @JonasElfström You can do it for 1-D arrays too, just not using `new []` syntax.  You have to use `Array.CreateInstance` and specify the bounds of each dimension.

Comment: @DStanley Each dimension on a 1-D array? You lost me and I don't find such a CreateInstance at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @JonasElfström I meant _in general_.  The overload can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a(v=vs.110).aspx). You could use arrays with one item to create a "1-D" array.