# Vba Type-Statement conversion to C#

Tags: c#, vba, types

This can probably be accomplished very easily but I have the following statement in VBA:

```
Type testType
    integerArray(5 To 100) As Double
End Type
```

How can I accomplish the same in C#?

@Edit 14:16   08-07-2015

In my belief this is not the same as the question mentioned. This is a question how to convert the Type statement with an array inside. The question mentioned is only about an array with it's starting index.

Comment: Can you please explain what `integerArray(5 To 100) As Integer` do exactly in VBA?

Comment: I can't find the exact definition on the web, but it is either accessible from index 5 to 100 or it can contain values between both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializing an array on arbitrary starting index in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82943/initializing-an-array-on-arbitrary-starting-index-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Are you sure that anything else than `0` is allowed? If i try the code in VB.NET(which is upwards compatible) i get a compiler error: _"Array lower bounds can be only '0'"_ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7c10x(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually C# does not support those kind of arrays based on any other start-index then zero.

However you may do.

```
double[] myArray = new double[96];
```

Alternatvily you may create a dictionary with indexes as keys and the actual value:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<int, double>();
```

Comment: It should actually be ```96``` elements ... ```new double[96]``` because in VBA the array(5 to 100) has 96 elements.

Comment: Does integerArray(5 To 100, 200 To 300) As Double means; An array from 5 to 100 and 200 to 300. (Thus 195 places?)

Comment: this means array with 96 elements where each this element has 101 another elements. So if i count right: 9696 elements.